# Python string conditional statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement, formatting

Is there a way or some sort of library that lets you compare string easily? It's difficult to explain, but here's an example:

```
str = "Hi World!"

if str == "(Hello | Hi) World!":
   print("You said either 'Hi World!' or 'Hello World!'")
```

In this example (of course, it wouldn't actually work,) if the string is either 'Hi World!' or 'Hello World!,' then it would return True. I am pretty sure that there's a name for this, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: One option would be `str.endswith('World!')`

Comment: Regex is close to your conditional which would be: `if re.match(r'(Hello|Hi) World!', str):`

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries focused on natural language processing that can help you achieve what you want.. that really depends on the complexity of what you want to build.

[NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) - provides several features and is pretty easy to use

However, for the specific case you've mentioned, might be the case of using a [spell check](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/) or see [edition distance](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) for pre-loaded close words